# Passing string to another component Angular

Tags: angular, components, frontend

I have a list with a lot of equipments. Each equipment has a button called "Detalhes". If I click in this button, I want to show just the info about that specific equipment (passing serialnumber, for example). How can I pass the serial number after switch between component?

Here's my html for the first page:

```
<div *ngFor="let equipment of equipments" class="card small card-small">
    <p>{{ equipment.equipmentName }}</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card-content">
        {{ equipment.serialnumber }}
        <p>
          <a href="/equipDetail">Detalhes</a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a (click)="open(modalcontent, equipment)">Editar</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

/equipDetail is the component that I want to show, after user click. This component should have all the data about the equipment, I can get this data with http calls if I get the serialnumber first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use angular routing, so you can just define router parameter like (let's suppose that your details component is called `DetailsComponent`):

### Router config

```
....
{ path: 'equipDetail/:serialNum', component: DetailsComponent }
....
```

You can set redirection parameter in html using `<a>` like:

### Link

```
....
<a [routerLink]="['/equipDetail', equipment.serialnumber]">Detalhes</a>
....
```

And you can read it in `DetailsComponent` like:

### Parameter usage

```
....
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
....
ngOnInit() {
   this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       const serialNum = params['serialNum'];
       // here you can use var serialNum to make a request to fetch data
   });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm.

Comment: Sure. I'm glad that it helped.